# How to make script exit on first error occurrence in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the function below where i pass in two arrays. I would like the script to exit on the first occurrence of an error.
I tried different variations but i can't make the script to stop early.

I have tried to use `($LastExitCode -eq 0)` it doesn't seem to work, all the scripts still continue running.

I also tried `If ($? -ne "True")` it doesn't work either, all the tests don't run at all.

```
function Run-Coverage {

    param($openCoverPath,$testExecutorPath,$dllPath,$output)

& $openCoverPath `
-threshold:100 `
-register:user `
-target:$testExecutorPath `
-targetargs:"$dllPath" `
-output:$output `

}

function Run-Tests
{
    param($Dll,$Xmls)

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $Dlls.length; $i++) 
    {
        $TestParam = $Dlls[$i]
        $resultParam = $Xmls[$i]
        $dllPath = -join("`"",$projectBasePath,$TestParam," ","/TestCaseFilter:`"(TestCategory!=RequiresData)`"","`"")
        $output = -join($outputPath,$resultParam)

        try
        {
            Run-Coverage -openCoverPath $openCoverPath -testExecutorPath $testExecutorPath -dllPath $dllPath -output $output
        }
        catch
        {            
            Write-Host "Exiting loop"
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `[CmdletBinding()]` as the first line inside the function (above the `param()` block), you can call the function with added `Common` parameters like [ErrorAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1#erroraction), [ErrorVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1#errorvariable) etc.

```
try {
    Run-Coverage -openCoverPath $openCoverPath -testExecutorPath $testExecutorPath -dllPath $dllPath -output $output -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    throw
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Paolo answered - you can do it easily using `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` or make it a little bit custom using:

```
trap {
    Write-Host "Exception occured: $($_.Exception.Message)";
    #Some action to do with the error
    exit 1;
}
```